# Instructing Google Chrome to stop client-side validation

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, client-side

Google Chrome appears to proactively enforce client-side validation. Here is an example of what I'm seeing:

[image]

In this case, I have no client-side validation scripts (*yet*) although I have set the pattern attribute with a regular expression. Is there a way to instruct Chrome (*and possibly other browsers*) to **NOT** volunteer validation services?

```
pattern="(44)?0?[1-9](0[0-9]{8})"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `novalidate` attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_form_novalidate.asp

Comment: I tried this for input elements but that didn't work. But it does work at the form level. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `pattern` attribute is *meant* to specify a rule to be applied by the browser, even when JavaScript is disabled. If you don’t want that, don’t use the attribute. If you want to remove the browser’s implementation of the checks when JavaScript is enabled, remove the attribute in your JavaScript code (possibly after storing its value so that you can construct a JavaScript regex from it).

Comment: @JukkaKKorpela I wouldn't mind but the error message provides little or no assistance. Is there a way to provide a message to supplement their popup?

Comment: The `title` attribute can be used to specify the supplementary text. Your example has such an attribute, though its value is rather generic text. In the given case, you could instead use
`title="Format: 44 (optional), 0 (optional), a digit, 0, and exactly 8 digits; no punctuation`. (This corresponds to the regular expression, though perhaps not the intentions; and it is usually better to write your form data handler to ignore punctuation and spaces than to tell people not to use them.)